# Pulseaudio: "virtual" sink just for controlling volume

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

I got a box that runs XBMC and other media apps, and various apps that play status sounds.

I'd like to have two "virtual" sinks (basically just for controlling the volume of a group of applications), one for status sounds and one for Multimedia. I've experimented with various pulseaudio modules, without any success.

I know how to assign applications to specific sinks, but how to create this kind of "just change volume and forward to the default sink"-sinks?